# Referring to a plural noun as singular

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Their mistakes **is** what saved Snowden because otherwise he would be in prison now.

*Source: The Putin Interviews by Oliver Stone*

imho 'is' refers  to the noun 'what' that is from the right side of the verb 'to be' that is quite unusual for me. Why does this verb take a form regardless of the noun that precedes it? Is it possible to use 'are' in this case?

ps
I've seen the similar topic - [Referring to a plural noun as singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204929/referring-to-a-plural-noun-as-singular)
But it didn't help me to understand the usage

Comment: It's hard to see how this is not a duplicate. Are you a native speaker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Agreement in "\[Singular Noun\] Is/Are \[Plural Noun\]"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/agreement-in-singular-noun-is-are-plural-noun)

Comment: @tchrist I think the other duplicate more accurately reflects the Dirty Hippy's confusion

Comment: @SteveES Your link is to a question whose answers explain that a verb agrees not with its complement but with its subject. It doesn't include situations where notional agreement rules.

Comment: There is a strong case for considering the mistakes as a grouped factor. However, the result here sounds outlandish. I'd revise to 'What saved Snowden is their mistakes; if these hadn't been made' he'd ...'.

Comment: If this is a transcript of a live interview, it may well just be an error—our tongues get ahead of our brains sometimes when we're speaking, and things like tense agreement can get mixed up. These kinds of errors are usually corrected when writing up journalistic interviews (along with dropping out all of the *uh*s and *um*s and smoothing over sentence fragments and other disjointed statements), but they're very common in speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is wrong.

> Their mistakes are what saved Snowden

From https://books.google.com/books?id=4BMkDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT59&lpg=PT59#v=onepage&q&f=false